# Raid driver: failed to init SCSI host 0

Tags: linux, raid

I have an **[LSI MegaRAID 9440-8i](https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/raid-controllers/megaraid-9440-8i)** RAID controller. This controller **works fine in my PC**, i.e. it is recognized by Linux and I can see the disk connected.

---

When I put this controller into my server, it shows up in the BIOS only, i.e. I can manage the controller in the BIOS, create RAID volume, etc.

---

But, when I boot Linux I get this error:

```
Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
megaraid_sas 0000:18:00.0: Init cmd return status FAILED for SCSI host 0
megaraid_sas 0000:18:00.0: Failed from megasas_init_fw 5559
```

and the controller is not recognized, ie `lsscsi` or `fdisk` shows no disks, kernel module `megaraid_sas` is not loaded.

---

What does the problem mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You did not describe your server at all, please add all needed information.

Comment: You might be asked to describe your PC (where it actually works) too.

Comment: Also, where do you see those messages, I presume in `dmesg`?

Comment: Apart from HW, you will also have to put enough information about the operating systems in which it does work and in which it does not, exact versions, configs, etc. please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular situation, the Linux Kernel module `megaraid_sas` is failing to load and thus you device is unknown for the system.

Needed infos (at least):

- Server and PC distro
- Server and PC Kernel version
- Output of `dmesg | grep megaraid` on both of your machines

The error you have on your server `Init cmd return status FAILED for SCSI host` was introduced with this [patch](https://isrc.iscas.ac.cn/gitlab/mirrors/git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto/commit/2d2c2331673cf7c525b44f31c766930bad18007a) and later modified with this other [patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10300435/) to the driver `megaraid_sas` in the Kernel v4.14

**Possible solutions:**

- This issue may occur regarding your DMA settings on the bios (SME or else); [reference](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1906.2/02015.html); you may try a different settings for the DMA on the bios.
- A different (newer) kernel version may probably fix the problem as the questioned module/driver is actively developed and [had merged a lot of changes lately.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master/drivers/scsi/megaraid/megaraid_sas_fusion.c)

Answer (score -3):

Please download the RAID controller drivers from the following site and Install the kernel module.

https://www.broadcom.com/support/download-search?pg=Storage+Adapters,+Controllers,+and+ICs&pf=RAID+Controller+Cards&pn=MegaRAID+9440-8i&pa=&po=&dk=

Install or Update the driver using Generic RPM's

1. Boot the System
2. Open the Terminal
3. Download the driver from the above link

Example:

```
wget https://docs.broadcom.com/docs-and-downloads/raid-controllers/raid-controllers-common-files/MR_Linux_Drv_7.12-07.712.02.00-1.tgz
tar -xzf MR_Linux_Drv_7.12-07.712.02.00-1.tgz
cd generic_srpm
rpm -ivh megaraid_sas-07.712.02.00-1.src.rpm
```

4. Reboot the system to load the driver

In case if you have an issue with booting OS then you need to create a driver update disk with the USB drive and install the megaraid_sas drivers.